# Variable type of template lambda (C++)

Tags: c++, c++20

I'm implementing a lambda as variable.
In C++20 it works this way:

```cpp
auto lambda = []<typename T>() -> const T& {
   ...
};
```

Now I want to store this kind of lambda function as a member variable of a struct:

```cpp
struct A {
    ??? m_lambda;
    A(??? lambda) : m_lambda(lambda) {}
};
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Why can't you just make it a named struct with a `template<typename T> operator()` overload? Why does it have to be an anonymous type?

Comment: "*Now I want to store this kind of lambda function as a member variable of a struct*" Does `A` need to take "a lambda", or does it need to take "any callable object with a certain signature"? Because those aren't the same thing. Because if it is "a lambda", the only value a caller could pass is a default-constructed instance of that type. Which will do *exactly* the same thing as if you default constructed it. So there's no reason to take a parameter.

Comment: But the only way to call that function is to say `lambda.operator()<type>()`. Are you sure this is something you need? And are you sure this is something that needs to be done via a lambda? And how do you expect a user to supply a different function, if the type of the functor (and therefore its `operator()` implementation) is baked into your `A` class?

Comment: @Nicol Bolas thank you for your answer.
I got exactly that problem: "the only value a caller could pass is a default-constructed instance of that type". I think I'll try to find another solution.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm trying to do: [Example](https://pastebin.com/xEzdSpxQ).
I thought that could be solved with a template lambda, but I didn't know how.

Comment: Why not just use a `void*` directly? The conversion is always going to be the same, right? Or even better, just use a `std::any`. The problem has already been solved; just use that solution.

Comment: If I use a `void*`, there are possible type punnings, that I want to avoid.
For example if I use a `int` and cast it to `float`.
`std::any` causes a **bad_any_cast** exeption.

Comment: If you want to "avoid" those "type punnings", then you *do* want an error if someone tries them, which is exactly what `any` will produce. So do you want to avoid them or not? If you erase a type (however you do it), and then try to re-introduce the type, that type must be provided at the introduction point. Therefore, you must have some response to the situation where the type provided is not the same as the erased type. `void*`'s response is a shrug of undefined behavior. `any`'s response is a nullptr or exception. What do you want your response to be?

Comment: @Nicol Bolas
Ah okay understand. There is no solution for a "static_any_cast". Thank you!
I want to have **nullptr** as response if the cast is invalid.

Comment: It would have helped if you had [*started* with that question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Answer (score 4):

You store any templated lambda the same ugly way you store ordinary ones:

```
constexpr auto lambda = []<typename T>() {};

struct Foo{
    decltype(lambda) m_lambda;
    Foo():m_lambda(lambda){}
};
```

This works because it is `operator()` that is actually templated, not the automatically-generated lambda type.

If you do not rely on inlining any calls to the lambda (for performance), you can store it in `std::function<Ret(Args)>` for correct signature.

`std::function` is also the only* option if the lambda cannot be defined before `Foo` as seems to be the case of your constructor.

```
struct A {
    std::function<void()> m_lambda;
    // Not a lambda per se.
    A(std::function<void()> lambda) : m_lambda(std::move(lambda)) {}
};
```

The above is not a lambda exactly because it doesn't really make sense most of the time to take a lambda as parameter as each has a distinct type making the argument effectively redundant.

*One can always make `A` a class template and use CTAD for deduction, not sure you want to go that way though.

Comment: I tried the second way with `std::function` but I want the lambda to return const T&. I see I forgot to write that.

Comment: @AnJoElLp4532110 Alright, can you add a little example how you plan to use that? Because that type has to be propagated outside right? Likely making the class template a valid choice unless you can go with the first example.

Comment: I want to have a template class named `Entry<T>` inside a `std::map<std::string, Entry<void>*>`.
The Entry contains a value variable from type T.
The base type of the `Entry<T>` is `Entry<void>`.
Now I want to get the `Entry<void>*` from the map and cast it to any type.

Comment: @AnJoElLp4532110: But you can't cast it to "any type"; you can only cast it to `Entry<T>`. So you have to know what `T` is when you do the cast. And C++ already has `std::any` which handle all this stuff.

Answer (score 3):

In c++20 you can do:

```
struct Foo
{
    decltype([] <class T> () {/* ... */ }) m_lambda {};
};
```

That being said it doesn't make any sense to store a lambda as a data member. Lambdas cannot change so a method is the simple, preferred alternative.

Comment: @AnJoElLp4532110 yea, you need C++20

Comment: This causes a compiler error: \
error: lambda-expression in unevaluated context only available with ‘-std=c++2a’ or ‘-std=gnu++2a’ \
    5 |   decltype([]<typename T>()->const T& {}) lambda{}; \
      |

Comment: @AnJoElLp4532110 yea, you need C++20 ... wow ... deja vu

Comment: @AnJoElLp4532110 You need C++20 just to use a template parameter list in a lambda anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Since your lambda is templated, you will need to contain the lambda directly in your object.

Fortunately, it's quite easy to do in C++20 (and C++17):

```
auto lambda = []<typename T>() -> const T& {
   // ...
};

template<typename L> // <-- L is the lambda type
struct A {
    L m_lambda;
    A(L lambda) : m_lambda(lambda) {}

    void foo() {
        // Can call using many types using the template
        int const& a = m_lambda.template operator()<int>();
        float const& b = m_lambda.template operator()<float>();
    }
};

int main() {
    auto my_a = A{lambda}; // construct using the lambda and CTAD
    my_a.foo();
}
```

If on the contrary you need `A` to only call one version of the template, you can wrap the lambda in another lambda:

```
struct A {
    std::function<int const&()> m_lambda;

    A(auto const& lambda) : m_lambda{
        [lambda]{ return lambda.template operator()<int>(); }
    } {}

    void foo() {
        // Can call and get a int const reference back
        int const& a = m_lambda();
    }
};
```